# PHP - Java opt() for arrays to set fallback value

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder if there is a PHP solution for Java's `opt()` function.

For example: In some cases I get a `$_GET` parameter, in some not. I'd like to to something like this:

```
$myVar = $_GET.opt('myParam', 'whatever');
```

If `myParam` is not set, `myVar` is set to the string "whatever".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ifnull(array &$array, $key, $default){
    if(!isset($array[$key])){
        $array[$key] = $default;
    }

    return $array[$key];
}
```

OR

```
function ifnull(array &$array, $key, $default){
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```